# How i can set orientation screen 'PORTRAIT'

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I think many Titanium developers go through this problem:
How to restrict application orientation to PORTRAIT

I've tried in `app.xml`, creating files `Manifest.xml` but with no success
Have you tried putting in the properties window "PORTRAIT" did not work. even tried this code

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function (e){
  Ti.Android.currentActivity.setRequestedOrientation(Ti.Android.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
})
```

I'm using TabGroup and three window associated with it.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

From now on, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/40001/android-force-orientation) or [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119538/how-to-lock-orientation)?

Normally, you would put `android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in each activity declaration in your android manifest

Comment: The titanium it manipulates the activity internally. I can not use activity (at least to my knowledge)

Comment: I do not know if any component can be TabGroup or something that is hindering the use of Portrait, i'm using TabGroup and Window

Comment: you say you changed app.xml, do you mean tiapp.xml? http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119538/how-to-lock-orientation

Comment: what about this? http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/09/locking-android-orientation-mode.html